# HKWirelessSDK - Component already exists

Tags: audio

When launching my application on my iOS or Android device I get an error message stating that "X" component already exists. What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you don't have any other instances of any apps with the SDK running in the background. There can only be one instance of the SDK running per device.